# How to write data to the json file using $http post method in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, json, http

I have a json file containing an array of objects, I would like to know the $http post method to add another object to this json (containing the array of objects). Assume all 3 files in the same folder. This has to be done in angularjs. Please help & for any additional details, just ask. Cheers!

--contact_details.json---

```
[{
  "name": "Darshil Patira",
  "number": "9829038347",
  "image": "images/dawn_scenic.jpg",
  "email": "darshilpatira@gmail.com"
}, {
  "name": "Sujith V",
  "number": "9756423129",
  "image": "images/blue_ocean.jpg",
  "email": "sujithv@gmail.com"
}]
```

---addcontact.html---

```
<div class="form-style">
    <div class="form-style-heading">
        Provide your information
    </div>
    <form name="reviewForm" action="" ng-submit="addcontact()" ng-controller="addContactController">
        <label for="field1">
            <span>Name<span class="require">*</span>
            </span>
            <input type="text" class="input-field" name="field1" ng-model="name" required />
        </label>
        <label for="field2">
            <span>Email<span class="require">*</span>
            </span>
            <input type="text" class="input-field" name="field2" ng-model="email" pattern="[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,3}$" required />
        </label>
        <label for="field3">
            <span>Telephone<span class="require">*</span>
            </span>
            <input type="text" class="tel-number-field" name="field3" ng-model="number" pattern=".{5,10}" required />
        </label>
        <input type="file" name="pic" accept="image/jpg">
        <label>
            <span>&nbsp;</span>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </label>
    </form>
</div>
```

---app.js(Controller)---

```
var app = angular.module("mainApp", ['ngRoute']);

app.controller('addContactController',function($scope,$http){
    var dataobj = { 'name':$scope.name, 'email': $scope.email, 'number':$scope.number };
    $http.post('contacts_details.json',dataobj);
});
```

Comment: You can't rely on angularjs (which is a front framework) to update files or database. You need a server (java, PHP, nodejs...) to make request and update shared content.

Comment: Change a json... does not make a lot of sense.. Where is your json? In a javascript variable? you want to store it on a server? Please try to explain a bit more what you want to reach...

Comment: using Front End Framework how u r going to update  your local Json files , if u need the file should be in server

Comment: Thanks Paqman! I had some idea about it, but wasn't sure, So I asked! @Paolof76 , that json is another file having only the objects array as shown. And everything is in my desktop folder only.

Answer (score 0):

Angular does not know how to write to the file system. It is up to the **server** to interpret the HTTP request into a database/persistence call.

Example:

```
.controller('someCtrl', function($http){
 var baseUrl = ... ;

 $scope.doPost = function(){
  $http.post(baseUrl + '/resource', {param1: 1, param2: 2});
 }
});

//In server (NodeJS?)
var fs = require('fs'); //File system module
server.post('/resource', function(request, response){ //Every HTTP post to baseUrl/resource will end up here
 console.info('Updated myJSON.json');
 fs.writeFile('myJSON.json', request.body, function(err){
  if(err) {
   console.error(err);
   return response.status(500).json(err); //Let the client know something went wrong
  }
  console.info('Updated myJSON.json');
  response.send(); //Let the client know everything's good.
 });
});
```

Comment: Thanks Muli Yulzary , but I can't make out what are you trying to accomplish, can you please explain?

Comment: You are mixing front-end with back-end jobs. Your server should be the one that updates the `.json` file, not the other way around. In my example you only call the `.post()` method in your controller. It is the server's job to update the JSON file and notify the client whenever it was a successful update or not. The second part of the code (below the first comment) is an example of back-end code written in node.js

Comment: That cleared things a bit! But I don't know  back-end technologies(node.js here). Will the baseurl above be the path of the json? Also will there be a seperate file for the server code written above by you, if yes, by what extension? if not, in which file should it be included?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to serve .json just for development, you might try [json-server](https://github.com/typicode/json-server). It is a quick and easy option -- great for development where you don't have access to the server but still need/can use the json data via api.